# ORACLE insert error integrity constraint parent key not found when it exists

Tags: sql, oracle, foreign-keys, sql-insert, create-table

First table

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE PLAN
  2  (
  3  grade       char(1),
  4  sectionid    char(10),
  5  courseid    char(5),
  6  sin     char(9),
  7  constraint    planPK
  8  primary key    (sin,sectionid),
  9  constraint    sinFK
 10  foreign key    (sin)
 11  references    STUDENT(sin),
 12  constraint    sectionsFK
 13  foreign key    (courseid,sectionid)
 14  references    SECTION(sectionnum, courseid));
```

second table

```
CREATE TABLE SECTION
(
sectionnum         char(5),
courseid           char(5),
instructorName     varchar(20)
constraint         sectionidPK
primary key        (sectionnum,courseid)
)
```

course and section exist in section table but when inserting values it errors out saying primary key not found.

Answer (score 3):

In the definition of table `plan`:

```
constraint    sectionsFK
    foreign key    (courseid, sectionid)
    references    SECTION(sectionnum, courseid)
```

From the names of the columns, I suspect that you want things the other way around:

```
constraint    sectionsFK
    foreign key    (sectionid, courseid)
    references    SECTION(sectionnum, courseid)
```

The ordering of columns is important, so tuples of values can properly match.

I would also suggest fixing the datatypes so they are identical: `sectionnum` is `char(5)` in table `section`, so `sectionid` in table `plan` should also be `char(5)` instead of `char(10)`.

Comment: That says you've supplied a SIN number (Student Id Number, I'm guessing) that does not exist in your STUDENT table. I suggest that you A) see if you can figure out what the problem is, and B) if you can't figure it out post a new question regarding this new problem you've found. And while you're at it, I suggest that you accept this answer by clicking the check mark under the vote total to the left of this answer. Thanks.